# What is the best practice to build some timer job in Azure to read xml and create list item?

Tags: office-365, list-item, xml, azure

I have some businese case where I need to build some timer job. This timer job will be scheduled 1 time each day. It will read in some folder all xml files. For each xml file the job needs to get some information and create a new list item in Office 365 site. I am thinking about to build a web job in Azure. But I dont know what the best practice is to read the xml file which is available on server intern. Maybe something like ftp? Or is it possible to make a ftp location in Azure to store there the xml files.

Comment: Azure Functions (for timer executions) and Blob Storage (for storing files).